# How to update every mysql row after specific interval of time?

Tags: mysql, jsp, phpmyadmin

I went through lots of links but still I am confuse about the way that I could use.

I have mysql database at server side,when user hits server with some values, at same time I save current time of server also.(jsp is used at server side)

Now I want to update some values from row after specific interval of time from current time which saved in database.(Every row has different current time value.)

Comment: UPDATE ...WHERE   DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), yourDate) >= whatever or use CREATE EVENT.

Comment: @Mihai its necessary to run .jsp script after specific interval of time? because server side script is run only when user hit it.

Comment: For CREATE EVENT is a mysql only deal,you only need to enable event scheduler,for UPDATE you need to run it manually.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use the MySQL events. In this tutorial, you have an example of how to configure this via phpMyAdmin: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ZRZoCsrKis.